# How to create a new column using a function that requires multiple columns as arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Yield function that takes several arguments and a dataframe that includes multiple columns that contain the inputs for the arguments.

```
def yield(price, par, maturity, coup, freq)

df:

Name    Price    Years_to_Maturity    Coup
abcd    98       4.5                  375
efgh    94       3                    425
```

I want to create a new column called "Yield" in the dataframe by applying the function using the columns in the dataframe but I have been unable to do this successfully.

I know the function works with direct inputs but I'm struggling to get it to work with multiple columns and constants (I want par and frequency to be constant). I want to apply the function to each row, something like:

```
df["Yield"] = df.apply(yield(df["price"], 100, df["Years_to_Maturity"], df["Coup"], 2), axis=1)
```

I've tried using the below approach that I found on a similar answer but i get a TypeError due to missing a required positional argument. I've tried to solve this but get other errors instead.

```
df['new_column_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['value_1'], x['value_2']), axis=1)
```

How can I create a new column using the function by inputting a combo of existing columns and fixed values?

Answer (score 0):

You lambda function is almost correct, try the following:

```
df["Yield"] = df.apply(lambda row: yield(row.Price, 100, row.Years_to_Maturity, row.Coup, 2), axis=1)
```

Remember that yield is a keyword in Python and is therefore not a recommended name for a function, it could lead to some nasty errors.

Comment: Amazing! This worked perfectly, thanks! My function wasn't actually called yield, I just thought it worked for the example, so nasty errors should be a minimum. Appreciate all the help, regardless though. I knew I was close but just couldn't get it down.